# Datagridview cellcontent click event not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms, events, datagridview

I wrote an event to retrieve the first cell value of the clicked cell's row on `CellContentClick` event in `datagridview`. but the event is getting raised only when i click the third cell and not getting raised when i click the first or second cell of datagridview.
Please help me.

Comment: paste some relevant code please

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to implement the `CellClick` event instead of `CellContentClick` event

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   DataGridView theGrid = sender as DataGridView;
   if(theGrid != null)
   {
      DataGridViewCell selectedCell = theGrid.SelectedCells[0];
      //Do your logic here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to Rami's answer, you will also need to update the default generated code in your Form's `Designer.cs`.

Original code:

```
this.dataGridView1.CellContentClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellClick);
```

Change it to:

```
this.dataGridView1.*CellClick* += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_CellClick);
```